# Error Updating View After Publishing Nuget Package Via API

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

We recently found several release pipelines that were using a deprecated version of the nuget API to update the View on a published nuget package (Setting Prerelease / Release on the package).  After updating the web service calls to be compliant with the 5.1 api we are getting the following error when calling this web service to set attributes on a published package

**Web Service:**

> `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org_name>/_apis/packaging/feeds/<feed_name>/upack/packages/<package_name>/versions/2.0.20126.03?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

**Error:**

> The package version provided is invalid. Universal package versions must be lowercase SemVer 2.0 versions without build metadata. The package version must be under 128 characters, and major/minor/patch must each be less than or equal to 2147483647

I am new to SemVer and publishing Nuget packages, any idea how to go about resolving the issue?  The artifact publishes with the version number as above `2.0.20126.03`

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here. According to your question, you want to promote nuget packages view, but the api you call is for universal package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script in the powershell task to see if it works.

```
$token = "Enter your Pat here"

$url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/packaging/feeds/FeedID/nuget/packagesbatch?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "data": {
    "viewId": "Release"
  },
  "operation": 0,
  "packages": [{
    "id": "YourPackageName",
    "version": "PackageVersion",
    "protocolType": "nuget"
  }]
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

You can set `PreRelease/Release` in viewID to promote nuget packages in Azure DevOps feed view from `@local` to `@pre-release` to `@release`.

In addition , you can also try [Promote package to Release View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task) extension to promote packages in a feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<feed_name>/upack/packages
```

**upack** means Universal package instead of nuget package, the nuget package related rest api is [{feedId}/**nuget**/packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

For Universal package, based on this document: [Publish a Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#publish-a-universal-package)

> Package names must be lowercase and can use only letters, numbers, and dashes (-). Package versions must be lowercase Semantic Versioning (SemVer) 2.0.0 without build metadata (+ suffix).

Your version/name is invalid, you could use 4.0.20126-0.3 or 4.0.20126-3 instead.